# Move [maui] posts to [.net-maui], and force disambiguation on [maui]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

I believe nearly all existing [maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui) posts should be moved to [.net-maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-maui). An attempt to use [maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui) should force disambiguation.

HISTORY:

When [.NET Maui](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui) came into existence, the first tag that people created to refer to it was [maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui).

Recently, a more descriptive tag [.net-maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-maui) was created. They are both being used to tag questions on the same topic.

I think the more descriptive tag should prevail as the main one.

Of the 388 [maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui) posts, AFAIK all but [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238769/what-are-pbs-torque-and-maui-how-do-they-work-together) of them refer to the technology named .NET Maui. (I've been monitoring the tag fairly closely.)

Thanks to Miyaki for finding that post with a different use of Maui tag.

See Miyaki's comments re two possible alternative "maui" technologies to be given their own tags.

Comment: ok. I had no idea there was such a thing as a synonym-request, so that is good to know. The justification is that they are both terms that refer to **exactly the same thing**. I really don't know what more there is to say about it, except to ask some expert such as Gerald Versluis - the top answerer in both of those.

Comment: And here I thought we were talking about [scheduling and resource management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maui_Cluster_Scheduler)!

Comment: Ah ha!  Then its possible [maui] is a "bad" tag, due to its ambiguity! Nevertheless, it was created when .NET Maui came into existence, and is being used to tag most of those. Those should get re-directed to the more explicit tag.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for being reponsive! Maybe a short description for the uninitiated? I can see that the request is valid, but not everyone. Besides, unless we suddenly find enough SMEs to vote (if the synonym even can be created), it will require a mod to drop by. In any case, now that the question has the tag, feeds posted it in the relevant room.

Comment: It might even turn out to be a [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation] request given @MisterMiyagi's comment. In general, we are [trying to streamline](https://sotagburners.github.io/intro/) the tag handling process lately to make it somewhat manageable.

Comment: "ZERO of them refer to the technology mentioned by Miyagi" Can't say I'm surprised, it's pretty niche – especially for programming. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238769/what-are-pbs-torque-and-maui-how-do-they-work-together), though it's closed. Probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369584/maui-preventing-jobs-from-running-on-the-same-node) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681054/torquemaui-pbs-submitted-job-strange-startup) should have been tagged for (torque-)maui.

Comment: Ah, I actually saw that one when it came by. But it didn't have enough info to know that it was referring to a different "Maui" (unless one knew what "torque" referred to.) And as you know, despite having "Maui" in title, the other one isn't "tagged" Maui, so I never saw it. Regardless, I concur these are evidence for disambiguation. Have added that to tag and title.

Comment: There is a third meaning: [Multi-Adaptable User Interface](https://mauikit.org/). It was mentioned in [this 2022-04-29 Linux-related video](https://odysee.com/@TheLinuxExperiment:e/elon-to-open-source-twitter,-popos:0), at 09 min 50 secs. It is software development related (my emphasis): *"A free and modular* ***front-end framework*** *for developing user experiences ... Maui stands for Multi-Adaptable User Interface and allows any Maui app to run on various platforms + devices, like Linux Desktop and Phones, Android, or Windows."*

Comment: They ***seem*** to be spelled differently, *Maui* vs. *MAUI*, but this does not work in practice.

Comment: In the past day or so I just saw about 2 dozen maui/.net maui questions show up. Do we have a consensus for which to use? There were 9 new .net-maui, and 13 maui tagged questions in the last 24-48 hours.

Comment: "maui" is still the dominant one overall, by far. 786 to 221 posts. However, IMHO, It would be best to force "tag-disambiguation" when someone types that, and force it to be ".net-maui", which is the precise name of the technology.

Answer (score 3):

[maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui) and [.net-maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-maui) refer to the same thing: the [.NET Multi-platform App UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui). Given that more explicit tags are generally better to avoid naming conflicts or ambiguity, [maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maui) should be made a synonym of [.net-maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-maui). This way any future technologies in other languages that use the name or acronym of MAUI can be prefixed with their language, which is a common/standard naming scheme for tags on the site already.

Comment: Yep. Now we just need someone to merge the tags, and change `maui` to require disambiguation. :)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I don't know what the second half of your comment means. By merging/synonymizing the tags, [tag:maui] would no longer exist; it would automatically redirect/replace with [tag:.net-maui] whenever someone tried to use it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The two techniques are mutually exclusive. Comments mentioned that `maui` has other (rare) uses. To accomodate those, `maui` answers could be moved to `.net-maui`, and then `maui` tag could be marked with "requires disambiguation", so that anyone who types it sees a list of possible tags; they are no longer able to select "maui" itself. I only mentioned this because my original statement was to do exactly what you said. I modified my suggestion to accomodate those (rarely used) technologies. 99%+ of SO users (including me) would be happy with your answer.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I don't see any other existing uses for "Maui" that are still around, but if any future ones arise they can be given a less ambiguous tag as well. The goal would be for the vast majority of use cases of "Maui" (the .NET library) to automatically tag to the right language tag if someone is lazy/doesn't know. The more esoteric technologies tend to have more astute users as a matter of principle, and they tend to ask better-formed/more accurately-tagged questions.