# Review our technical responses for the 2023 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, announcement, survey-2023

> **Update on May 3rd, 2023:** Thank you for all the comments and suggestions! We have collected your responses and have completed reviewing your suggestions for the survey.

It is that time of year again when we ask you all to be our second pair of eyes on the annual Developer Survey! Below you will find the technology choices we would like to include in the 2023 survey. If you notice any additional options that should be included, please post an answer below with the name, category, and a brief description or references to why it should be included in this year's survey.

We have also heard your feedback on the Loved, Dreaded, Wanted analysis. We’re going to experiment with different analyses for this, aiming to remove the emotional attribution while still examining the responses for "Worked With and Want to Work With”.

We value your input, I promise.  While we are reviewing your answers here, keep in mind we may not reply to them unless we need clarification.  Any suggestions will be considered, but we will not necessarily be honoring all suggestions. That being said, we are very excited to kick off the survey next month and look forward to hearing from you.

We will be collecting feedback until **Friday, April 28, 2023**.

| Programming, scripting, and markup languages |
| --- |
| Ada, Apex, APL, Assembly |
| Bash/Shell |
| C, C#, C++, Clojure, COBOL, Crystal, CSS |
| Dart, Delphi |
| Elixir, Erlang |
| F#, Fortran |
| GDScript, Go, Groovy |
| Haskell, HTML |
| Java, JavaScript, Julia |
| Kotlin |
| Lisp, Lua |
| MATLAB |
| Nim |
| Objective-C, OCaml |
| Perl, PHP, PowerShell, Prolog, Python |
| R, Raku, Ruby, Rust |
| SAS, Scala, Solidity, SQL, Swift |
| TypeScript |
| VB.NET, VBA |
| Zig |

| Database environments |
| --- |
| BigQuery |
| Cassandra, ClickHouse, Cloud Firestore, CockroachDB, Cosmos DB, DBCouchbase, CouchDB |
| Datomic, DuckDB, DynamoDB |
| Elasticsearch |
| Firebase Realtime Database, Firebird |
| H2 |
| IBM DB2, InfluxDB |
| MariaDB, Microsoft SQL Server, MongoDB, MySQL |
| Neo4j |
| Oracle |
| PostgreSQL |
| Redis |
| Snowflake, SQLite, Supabase |

| Cloud platforms |
| --- |
| AWS |
| Cloudflare, Colocation |
| DigitalOcean |
| Firebase, Fly.io |
| Google Cloud |
| Heroku, Hetzner |
| IBM Cloud or Watson |
| Linode |
| Managed Hosting, Microsoft Azure |
| Netlify |
| OpenShift, OpenStack, Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, OVH |
| Scaleway |
| Vercel, VMware, Vultr |

| Web frameworks and technologies |
| --- |
| Angular, AngularJS, ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core |
| Blazor |
| CodeIgniter |
| Deno, Django, Drupal |
| Elm, Express.js |
| FastAPI, Fastify, Flask |
| Gatsby |
| jQuery |
| Laravel, Lit |
| NestJS, Next.js, Node.js, Nuxt.js |
| Phoenix, Play Framework |
| React, Remix, Ruby on Rails |
| Solid.js, Spring Boot, Svelte, Symfony |
| Vue.js |
| WordPress |

| Other frameworks and libraries |
| --- |
| .NET, .NET Maui |
| Apache Kafka, Apache Spark |
| Capacitor, Cordova |
| Electron |
| Flutter |
| GTK |
| Hadoop, Hugging Face Transformers |
| Ionic |
| Jax |
| Keras, Ktor |
| Maui, Micronaut |
| NumPy |
| OpenCV |
| Pandas |
| Qt, Quarkus |
| RabbitMQ, React Native |
| Scikit-learn, Spring Framework, SwiftUI |
| Tauri, TensorFlow, Tidyverse, Torch/PyTorch |
| Uno Platform |
| Xamarin |

| Developer tools | Developer environments |
| --- | --- |
| Ansible | Android Studio, Atom |
| Cargo, Chef | BBEdit |
| PHP Composer | CLion |
| Docker | DataGrip |
| Flow | Eclipse, Emacs |
| Godot, Godot Engine | Fleet |
| Homebrew | Geany, GoLand |
| Kubernetes | Helix |
| Maven | IntelliJ IDEA, IPython/Jupyter |
| Nix, Npm, NuGet | Kakoune, Kate |
| Pip, Pnpm, Podman, Pulumi, Puppet | Micro |
| Terraform | Nano, Neovim, NetBeans, Notepad++, Nova |
| Unity 3D, Unreal Engine | PhpStorm, PyCharm |
| Yarn | Qt Creator |
|  | RAD Studio (Delphi, C++ Builder), Rider, RStudio, RubyMine |
|  | Spyder, Sublime Text |
|  | TextMate |
|  | Vim, Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, VSCodium |
|  | WebStorm |
|  | Xcode |

| Operating systems |
| --- |
| AIX, Android |
| BSD |
| Chrome OS, Cygwin |
| Haiku |
| iOS, iPadOS |
| Linux-based |
| macOS |
| Solaris |
| TempleOS |
| Ubuntu |
| Windows, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) |

| Collaboration tools |
| --- |
| Adobe Workfront, Airtable, Asana, Azure DevOps |
| Basecamp |
| Cerri, Clickup, Confluence |
| DingTalk (Teambition), Document360, Doxygen |
| GitHub |
| Jira |
| Leankor, Linear |
| Markdown File, Microsoft Lists, Microsoft Planner, Miro, Monday.com |
| Notion, Nuclino |
| Planview Projectplace Or Clarizen |
| Redocly, Redmine |
| Shortcut, Smartsheet, Stack Overflow for Teams, Swit |
| Tettra, Trello |
| Wikis, Wimi, Workzone, Wrike |
| YouTrack |

| Communication tools |
| --- |
| Cisco Webex Teams, Coolfire Core |
| Discord |
| Google Chat, Google Hangouts Meet |
| IRC |
| Jitsi |
| Matrix, Mattermost, Microsoft Teams |
| RingCentral, Rocket.Chat |
| Signal, Skype, Slack, Symphony |
| Telegram Messenger |
| Unify Circuit |
| WhatsApp, Wickr, Wire |
| Zoom, Zulip |

| AI search options | AI development tools |
| --- | --- |
| Andi | Adrenaline, AWS CodeWhisperer |
| Bing AI | GitHub Copilot |
| ChatGPT | Mintlify |
| Google Bard | Replit Ghostwriter, Rubber Duck.AI |
| Metaphor | Synk Code |
| Neeva AI | Tabnine |
| Perplexity AI, Phind | Whispr AI |
| Quora Poe |  |
| WolframAlpha |  |
| You.com |  |

Comment: Current count (revision 7): 320 items

Comment: This could be done by [manually](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Apl) [correcting](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=ASP.Net) [them](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Gdscript) [one](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Html) [by](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Css) [one](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Vb.Net), but this calls for automation.

Comment: Related (ambiguity of *"Maui"* / *"MAUI"* - *"[Multi-Adaptable User Interface](https://mauikit.org/)"*? *"[Multi-platform App UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#.NET_MAUI)"?*): *[Move \[maui\] posts to \[.net-maui\], and force disambiguation on \[maui\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418134/move-maui-posts-to-net-maui-and-force-disambiguation-on-maui#comment910510_418134)*

Comment: "[Symphony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_(disambiguation)#Computer_science)" is ambiguous.

Comment: Nice technical list. Still unsure why Prosus needs such extensive _personal_ info on Developers. Where can I complain about the 2023 Developer Survey's list of _personal_ questions (age, state/country of residence, etc.)?

Comment: Is Dagger significant enough to be included as a competitor to Docker / Podman?

Comment: @jubilatious1, age and country of residence have been questions on the survey since the very beginning (2011- way before Prosus acquired Stack Overflow). [see for yourself](https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2011.zip)

Comment: ....and....they're not ___optional___.

Comment: What were the complaints about "Loved, Dreaded, Wanted"? It seems more informative to me than "Worked With/Want to Work With"

Comment: Actually, just noticed ya'll are finally dropping the "Loved, Dreaded, Wanted" choice - gotta give credit where credit's due - thanks for listening to the feedback! Those were really too emotionally charged (as well as useless from the standpoint of trying to ascertain the trends, mostly for the same reason).

Comment: 1) out of curiosity, should this be closed now, since the period for collecting feedback (which is the purpose of this post) has ended? 2) also, will there be any announcement about _how_ exactly our feedback was taken into account?

Comment: @user 1) nah, I'd not go for closing it - it's on-topic and can benefit from potential answers even if SE doesn't look at it anymore ("no longer reproducible" might be appropriate, but dunno if it's worth it); 2) judging from the previous years - not a chance there'll be one (although there will likely be an announcement of the survey going live which is when we usually learn of whether the suggestions were accepted. Good question, though, [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] I actually requested status tags on answers last year, and Jnat [promised to do it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417991/take-the-2022-developer-survey/417994#comment915861_418009) this year, but as you can see, SE seems to have forgotten about it as usual.

Comment: Looks like it went live as the wrongly-cased "Intellij", not as "IntelliJ IDEA" shown in this list.  Also "Maven (build tool)" instead of just "Maven".

Answer (score 100):

Out of curiosity, do query languages fit within the categories of "programming, scripting, and markup languages"? Or are they different? I.e. should that section be renamed to "Programming, scripting, query, and markup languages:"?

When you say "Bash/Shell", is "Shell" supposed to be a catch-all for shells like [the Bourne Shell (`sh`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), Zsh, C Shell, tcsh, Dash, Fish, etc.?

Why is Homebrew listed, but a bunch of other package managers aren't? Ex. APT, Chocolatey, pacman, etc.

Why was [Git listed last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417201/11107541), but not listed this year (nor other version control software / source control management software? Ex. [Apache Subversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) (SVN), [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/))?

And why is GitHub listed under Collaboration Tools, but not other similar platforms like BitBucket and GitLab?

Why is Maven listed, but not Ant or Gradle?

Why no C/C++ buildsystem technologies? [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [CMake](https://cmake.org), [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), [build2](https://build2.org/), [MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild), [QMake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html), [SCons](https://scons.org/). Some form of "what buildsystem tool alternative to CMake do you use" is a frequently rehashed question on r/cmake, so it'd be real nice to get data on this in a survey with as wide a reach as the SO dev survey. If this gets given its own category, I'd also like to see IDE-based "buildsystems" in it, such as Xcode, and Visual Studio Solutions.

I'm also interested to see what [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:C%2B%2B_compilers) C and C++ devs are supporting in their projects. Such a list would at the very least include GCC, LLVM's Clang, MSVC, and would do well to also include MinGW, Mingw-w64, Intel C++ Compiler, and some relatively newer blood like [Circle](https://www.circle-lang.org/).

I'm also curious about [C++ testing libraries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs#Testing)- of which some (I pulled the ones I know from the previous link) are: [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/libs/test/), [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), [cppunit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/), [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest), [Google Test](https://google.github.io/googletest) (see the full list to avoid my bias).

In the same list where there is GTK and Qt, it would be nice to see other [C++ GUI libraries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs#Graphic_user_interface), such as [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui), [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/), and [WxWidgets](https://wxwidgets.org/).

And how could I forget about C++ non-system package managers? Of which they include (but are not limited to): [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/), [Conan](https://conan.io/), [Spack](https://spack.io/), [Hunter](https://github.com/cpp-pm/hunter), and [build2](https://build2.org/) (it's [also a package manager](https://build2.org/faq.xhtml#why-package-managers)).

It would be interesting to know about what C++ language versions people are using in their projects. The same question goes for C, ECMAScript (related: [tsconfig's `target` field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target))

Under "Development Environments:"- no [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/)?

It might be useful to take a look at how other people are conducting similar surveys, such as JetBrains: which does [an overall survey](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2022/), and then [ecosystem specific ones](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2022/cpp/).

I'm kind of interested in what state-management technologies people are using in their Flutter projects. I remember when I tried to dip my toes in Flutter, it was quite overwhelming to see the list and try to pick one. See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options.

These highly language-specific technology categories can be conditionally made visible in the survey when the participant indicates that they are using the relevant contextual technology. Ex. Hide questions about C/C++ compilers if the participant hasn't selected that they use C++.

What about languages from the Hardware Description family? Ex. [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog), [System Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog).

#### Other capitalization errors

(I may have missed some)

##### Under "Programming, scripting, and markup language:"

"Apl" -> "APL", "Gdscript" -> "GDScript", "Html/Css" -> "HTML/CSS" (and why are they together? I would have put them separately), "Javascript" -> "JavaScript" (calling @PeterMortenson just to bug them :P), "Matlab" -> "MATLAB", "Ocaml" -> "OCaml", "Php", "PHP", "Powershell" -> "PowerShell", "Typescript" -> "TypeScript" (again, calling @PeterMortenson), "Vb.Net" -> "VB.NET" (or "Visual Basic (.NET)"?).

##### Under "Databases environments:"

"Sqlite" -> "SQLite".

##### Under "Cloud Platforms:":

"Digitalocean" -> "Digital Ocean", "Openshift" -> "OpenShift", "Openstack" -> "OpenStack".

##### Under "Web Frameworks and Technologies:"

"ASP.Net" -> "ASP.NET", "ASP.Net Core" -> "ASP.NET Core", "Codeigniter" -> "CodeIgniter", "Fastapi" -> "FastAPI", "Jquery" -> "jQuery" (quite surprised nobody caught this one), "Nest.js" (why not "NestJS"?), "React.js" (why not "React"?), "Solid.js" (why not "SolidJS"?), "Wordpress", "WordPress".

##### Under "Other Frameworks and Libraries:"

".Net" -> ".NET", ".Net Maui" -> ".NET MAUI", "Jax" -> "JAX", (out of curiosity, what is "Maui", and how is it different than ".NET MAUI"?), "Rabbitmq" -> "RabbitMQ", "Swiftui" -> "SwiftUI", "Tensorflow" -> "TensorFlow", "Torch/Pytorch" -> "Torch/PyTorch".

##### Under "Developer Tools:"

"Npm" -> "npm", "Nuget" -> "NuGet", "Pnpm" -> "pnpm".

##### Under "Development Environments:"

"Bbedit" -> "BBEdit", "Clion" -> "CLion", "Datagrip" -> "DataGrip", "Ipython/Jupyter" -> "IPython/Jupyter", "Phpstorm" -> "PhpStorm", "Pycharm" -> "PyCharm", "Rstudio" -> "RStudio", "Rubymine", "RubyMine", "Textmate" -> "TextMate", "Vscodium" -> "VSCodium", "Webstorm" -> "WebStorm".

##### Under "Operating Systems:"

"Aix" -> "AIX", "Bsd" -> "BSD", "IpadOS" -> "iPadOS", "MacOS" -> "macOS", "Templeos" -> "TempleOS", "Windows Subsystem For Linux" -> "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

##### Under "Collaboration Tools:"

"Stack Overflow For Teams" -> "Stack Overflow for Teams" (... no comment), "Youtrack" -> "YouTrack"

Comment: "Why is Git listed, but not Apache Subversion (SVN)?" Similarly, what happened to all the local version control tools? Not every company might be crazy enough to upload their business secrets to a 3rd party cloud outside their control - I'm guessing the majority does not, but maybe I'm out of the loop...?

Comment: Also interested in C++ linkers ([GOLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)), [GNU ld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)#GNU_linker), [LLVM lld](https://lld.llvm.org), [MOLD](https://github.com/rui314/mold), etc)

Comment: @Lundin You can host your own Git server though? Git is not tied to github and co.

Comment: _"These highly language-specific technology categories can be conditionally made visible in the survey when the participant indicates that they are using the relevant contextual technology."_ So much of the survey is web-dev focused, I wish the questions about web frameworks could also be gated by an earlier question about fields that a participant works in.

Comment: Similarly, I would be very interested in the language version that is used, which is also a question per language

Comment: So many of these would be very good additions. I'm especially extremely curious about the build system / package managers / test frameworks ones, since those are just incredibly valuable to have good information about.

Comment: I was also surprised by the missing Version controls, and as I only would add one other so seems silly to have a separate post, many of my students and peers (in certain distributed or VR based projects) are using Unity's [PlasticSCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/) as their primary and Unity is included in this list so why not its SCM system? Actually an interesting data point to me, do we use Unity but not Plastic or Plastic but not Unity?

Answer (score 44):

Lots of naming errors, mostly capitalization issues:

- "*.Js" -> "*.js"
- "Netbeans" -> "NetBeans"
- "Pycharm" -> "PyCharm"
- "Vscodium" -> "VSCodium"
- "Ipados" -> "iPadOS" ("Ipados" sounds like a Pokémon)

...okay, there are too many of these, I'm going to stop enumerating them specifically.  With a small number of exceptions (ChromeOS), this looks like it's been run through something that capitalizes the first letter of each word and nothing else; that's going to be incorrect in quite a few cases.

Naming errors that aren't just capitalization issues:

- "Intellij" -> "IntelliJ IDEA"
- "Google Bard AI" -> "Google Bard"

Comment: ""Ipados" sounds like a Pokémon" - Now I'm expecting pokemon easter eggs in the survey :p

Comment: Ok I fixed the ones you listed out here.  There's a lot of technology-specific naming convention nuance, I want to make sure I get it all correct.

Comment: @ErinAsks I had corrected the Pycharm stylizing last year and I corrected it again this year. Maybe it's better to reuse previous year listings that have already been copy-edited. I don't blame you in any way, there's so many possible stylings that no one person can get them all right without carefully looking up each word.

Comment: "_...okay, there are too many of these, I'm going to stop enumerating them specifically._" don't worry. [I gotchu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424293/11107541)

Comment: @ErinAsks To add even more nuance to the mess that is JS. AngularJS is AngularJS and not Angular.js :-)

Comment: @ErinAsks as user points out in [their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424293/208273), "IpadOS" is still mis-capitalized; it should be "iPadOS".

Comment: for the uninitiated reading @Zoe's comment, I assume it's a reference to [jokes of this variety](https://preview.redd.it/bka1gb843z7z.jpg?auto=webp&s=dcdbe1ba1ee065e369eb451dfa2e520f748d9de6)

Comment: No, it was mostly in the same chain as "can you exit vim?" and other fun questions from previous years. Real shame those were axed

Answer (score 36):

A recurring problem with this survey is that it doesn't cover embedded systems. If you look at last year's survey, 6.4% of the SO user base work with embedded systems. A minority, sure, but it also means that most of this survey is irrelevant to 6.4% of the target audience and that will reflect on the relevance of the survey as whole.

The tool chain for embedded development looks very different and I'm completely clueless about what a lot of the tools listed are for - you might as well ask a plumber if they use these tools. There are lots of niche IDEs, compilers and debuggers (and oscilloscopes) which are well-known in the embedded branch.

It would seem that the options are to either exclude embedded systems from the survey or expand the survey to cover embedded systems. Or perhaps make a separate survey regarding embedded systems, perhaps below https://electronics.stackexchange.com where it might fit in better.

Comment: A *minority* maybe, but that was also the essence of the most upvoted [Answer/Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417236/3799241) (+93) in last year's (2022) Review by @CodyGray... // Web-Automation is also completely missing from the Survey, like every year...

Comment: @chivracq Ah yeah now that you mention it, I remember that. +93 is quite significant as meta goes.

Comment: "A minority, sure, but it also means that most of this survey is irrelevant to 6.4% of the target audience" - might be a minority, but at 6.4%, it's pretty significant. It's not like there's a couple users being discarded here; it's at least 4000 (based on last year's 70000 responses)

Comment: The minority might be actually larger than that. I personally know developers who didn't took the survey because it wasn't appealing to them.

Answer (score 25):

### Developer Tools

Please add options for **bundle/build tools**. Webpack is the most well-known option, but it'd be interesting to see current usage and future trends vs other options.

Here are the ones I've encountered, along with a couple relatively newer ones from [@user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/user) and [@Samathingamajig](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12101554/samathingamajig) (ordered by GitHub stars):

| Build tool | GitHub stars |
| --- | --- |
| **[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)** | [~63k stars](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) |
| **[Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)** | [~55k stars](https://github.com/vitejs/vite) |
| **[Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)** | [~42k stars](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel) |
| **[Bun](https://bun.sh/)** | [~41k stars](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun) |
| **[esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/)** | [~35k stars](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) |
| **[SWC](https://swc.rs/)** | [~27k stars](https://github.com/swc-project/swc) |
| **[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)** | [~23k stars](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) |

Comment: I'm surprised Vite isn't on here (the existing survey) already. See also: [Bun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424311/12101554), has [~41k stars](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun)

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yeah, I was also surprised this subcategory was missing. I saw your post about Bun (which gave me the idea of adding star counts), but I'm not familiar with Bun. Do you think Bun also fits in this group of build tools? I see it includes a bundler, but I don't know if it's an independent bundler that can be used for arbitrary projects.

Comment: Bun is unique. It has all those other features I mentioned, but it can also be used just for the bundler. I'm 99% the bundler was the original project ("bun-"dler) and then grew significantly since then.

Answer (score 24):

There's three (major) flavors of .NET nowadays:

- .NET Framework (1.0-4.8), basically on life support forever.
- .NET Core (1.0-3.1), being [entirely out of support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).
- .NET 5 (out of support), 6 (Long-Time Support), 7 (Short-Time Support), 8 (preview). The next hot thing.

It would be interesting to see which of those three are still actively being developed in/for/against. In other words: I'd like to see the options:

- .NET Framework (optionally suffixed "1.0-4.8")
- .NET Core (optionally suffixed "1.0-3.1")
- .NET (optionally suffixed "5+")

I wouldn't like conflating them all under ".NET" (and definitely not ".Net"), which is akin to calling all Angular/AngularJS development just "Angular".

However, plenty of users of .NET don't know what to name what they're using. There is no such thing as .NET *Core* 5/6/7, but you'd be surprised at the amount of developers who call it that.

Answer (score 16):

Add "[Bun](https://bun.sh)" to "Web frameworks and technologies".

Bun is a JavaScript runtime like NodeJS and Deno. Instead of the V8 engine that NodeJS and Deno use, Bun uses [JavaScriptCore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore) (which powers Webkit/Safari).

They have impressive benchmarks, but also have cool features such as built-in TypeScript & JSX support, ESM & CommonJS compatibility, implementation of Web-standard APIs, and compatibility with NodeJS. It also has a built-in package manager, transpiler, bundler, and script/test runner

Bun has [40.7k stars on GitHub](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun) at the time of writing this ([Deno has 89k](https://github.com/denoland/deno)), so this isn't just some random project, it's actually used by several thousand developers.

Answer (score 15):

[Render](https://render.com) in the Cloud Platforms category.

- Render is [generally acknowledged as a modern replacement](https://hn.algolia.com/?dateRange=all&page=0&prefix=false&query=render%20heroku&sort=byDate&type=comment) for Heroku.
- Websites hosted on Render [served over 1 billion](https://twitter.com/anuraggoel/status/1638946186546794496) visitors in March.

*I work at Render.*

Comment: Would you like to disclose affiliation?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Why doesn't it have a Wikipedia entry?

Comment: Is that a requisite? fly.io doesn't have one that I can find, but is already included in the list.

Disclaimer: also work at Render

Answer (score 14):

Since [I still do not have an answer and it is still relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417209), I will just repost this:

> ##### Flow
>
> Is it [this Flow](https://flow.org/)? The static type checker that compiles to JavaScript? If so, it is a direct competitor to TypeScript. Yes, TS does a few more things but it does not make a lot of sense to have them listed under different places. TS is listed under "Programming, scripting, and markup language".

Answer (score 13):

1. Clarification:

   - What is `DBCouchbase` here? Is it Couchbase Server or Couch DB? Surely, not both?
2. Minor name correction:

   - DBCosmos -> Cosmos DB
3. Suggestion:

   - [RavenDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RavenDB) is missing from **Database environments** imo.

Answer (score 13):

Consider adding VB6 to the list of programming languages.

People claim that VB6 is still widely used and certainly there is a constant stream (trickle more than a torrent) of questions from what looks like new programmers to the language. Having this included on surveys would yield a much more objective picture of the trend for this language, perhaps coupled with some understanding of what motivates new developers / new development in a ~25-year-old frozen/dead language.

Comment: Re *"what motivates new developers"*: [Old text books](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-criticise-Yashavant-Kanetkar-books-like-Let-Us-C-Why-dont-more-people-use-Turbo-C)? [An account](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-colleges-in-India-still-use-Turbo-C++-instead-of-any-other-IDE/answer/Heeth-Jain)

Comment: Strictly speaking, VB6 is a native compiler and forms engine wrapped around the VBA language, which is very much alive as Microsoft still hasn't replaced it as the scripting language for Excel.

Comment: VBA is already on the list, and should remain a separate choice for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

Nitpick, but Ubuntu, Chrome OS, and (in some sense) WSL are Linux-based operating systems. (There may be others on the list that I missed; I picked these out just by quick glance.) Perhaps the general Linux should be "Other Linux-based"?

I would be interested in including at least Debian and CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat (separately or as a lump?) as well; these are almost certainly used in professional environments as much as Ubuntu, or more. Arch is popular on the desktop among sophisticated users, but then so are Gentoo, Mint, Slackware, etc.

Comment: Indeed, WSL is essentially a more tightly integrated virtual machine

Comment: Arch, Red Hat, Debian and Fedora really need to be on the list.

Comment: In fact, "_Debian based (except Ubuntu based)_", "_Ubuntu based_", "_slackware based_" and "_Red Hat based_" would make for interesting data-points too

Answer (score 11):

Add "[conda](https://docs.conda.io/)" to the "Developer Tools" category.

Answer (score 10):

##### Clarify if "Maven" just refers to the tool, or also the repository format

"Maven" could refer to the Maven build tool itself, or the Maven artifact repository format that it shares with other tools like Gradle.  As a user of only Gradle, but who gets Gradle dependencies from Maven repositories, I'm not sure if I should select that one or not.  It might be worth clarifying that.

Answer (score 10):

Should continuous integration & test automation tools appear on this list?

- [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/)
- [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29)
- [Travis CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travis_CI)
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/about/)
- [Buildbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buildbot)
- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)

Answer (score 8):

An additional candidate for **Other frameworks and libraries** might be [Polars](https://www.pola.rs), a relatively new but promising dataframe/series framework. It's relevant at least for **Rust** and **Python**, further **Node.js** and **R**, and has a **DuckDB** interface. (Already almost 17k GitHub-stars.)

Answer (score 7):

What about Microsoft Access for database environments? Will likely make the others look good due to an instant dreaded win (or whatever comes to replace that).

Comment: Excel also should be included somewhere if we are also including things like "collaboration tools" and "AI tools" which don't involve any programming these days (just "give ChatGPT a prompt and complain when the code doesn't work"), since programmers probably use it a bunch for all sorts of things. Or at the very least the Microsoft VBA Editor, since the VBA language is listed under programming languages. I mean, we also allow questions about Excel formula writing here...

Answer (score 7):

It would be nice to have [Solr](https://solr.apache.org/) added as a database, or Lucene, which it's built on.

Comment: Lucene isn't a database, it's a text indexing library.

Answer (score 7):

Is there any particular reason both *Godot* and *Godot Engine* are present in developer tools? I'd think one would be enough

Answer (score 5):

For Databases, [TiDB](https://www.pingcap.com/tidb/) should be included. It's the most popular database (open source or not) in the Asia Pacific region, and rapidly growing in North America and Europe, because of its strong answer to SQL scale and analytics.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: Add "[Wasmer](https://wasmer.io/)" to "Developer tools".

Wasmer is the most popular [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) server-side runtime. It allows running any program anywhere (such as the Python container running universally in the browser, or the server). Some people already see Wasmer as the logical evolution of Docker.

Wasmer also has a built-in package manager, ([WAPM](https://wapm.io/)).
Is being used by thousands of developers worldwide, and by companies such as Cloudflare, Vercel, Google, Apple and more.

WebAssembly is becoming increasingly popular for [edge computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_computing), [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), and [Web 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web3)... so I think it could make sense to include Wasmer in the 2023 survey!

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me if the intent is to be exhaustive, mention hidden gems, or something else. For example, the specific inclusion of TempleOS is puzzling considering a heap of distros are lumped together as "Linux-based". In any event, here are some suggestions, I hope they help!

**Programming, scripting, and markup languages**

- [Gemtext](https://gemini.circumlunar.space/docs/gemtext.gmi)
- Markdown / CommonMark
- [Mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org)
- LaTeX / TeX

**Web frameworks and technologies**

- [API Blueprint](https://apiblueprint.org)
- [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org) / Swagger
- [RAML](https://raml.org)

**Developer tools**

- [SonarLint](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarlint/)

Depending on what you're measuring, it might be informative to list the following in addition to pip (they all use pip underneath):

- [pdm](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/)
- [pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/)
- [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/)
- [poetry](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/)

**Collaboration tools**

- Bitbucket
- [GitLab CE (self-hosted)](https://about.gitlab.com/install/?version=ce)
- GitLab EE
- [Helix Core](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core)
- [Space](https://www.jetbrains.com/space/)
- [Unity Version Control](https://unity.com/solutions/version-control) / Plastic SCM

In general, it would be interesting to know how many people use in-house and/or self-hosted tools rather than SaaS.

**Continuous integration**

See [Seth's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424399/236081)

**Other frameworks and libraries**

- [Kivy](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/)
- [LangChain](https://pypi.org/project/langchain/)
- [Textual](https://pypi.org/project/textual/)

**Not sure where to put these**

- [Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) (including JSON-LD etc)
- [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev)
- [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Comment: Re *"specific inclusion of TempleOS is puzzling"*: Possibly because it has [an interesting history](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCgoxQCf5Jg), an eccentric creator who perished, and its idiosyncratic nature. Stack Overflow is mentioned [at 00 h 24 min 02 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCgoxQCf5Jg&t=24m2s).

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest [Sinatra](https://sinatrarb.com/) as a web framework. It's the second most popular Ruby web framework, behind Ruby on Rails, with over 11,000 GitHub stars.

Answer (score 4):

I am interested in the language or framework versions used, especially where breaking changes were introduced or the old version still appears in recent Stack Overflow questions.

This could be an optional additional field, only to be interpreted and visualized where there are significant differences.

Answer (score 3):

Can we split IPython/Jupyter (*Development environments* category):

1. **Separate out the "IPython" bit.** It has been over 8 years since IPython became the Project Jupyter ([*The big split*](https://blog.jupyter.org/the-big-split-9d7b88a031a7)). The meaning of IPython has changed since (it is no longer associated with notebooks per se, although `.ipynb` extension lingers on). IPython is a a great tool but grouping it together with Jupyter makes less sense nowadays than it used to.
2. **Use "Jupyter Notebook"** (with capital *N*). Jupyter is just a name of the project/set of standards rather than of an IDE. Many editors (VSCode, PyCharm) provide support for Jupyter toolset but are distinct IDEs.
3. **Add "JupyterLab"**. JupyterLab is the new interface for Jupyter notebooks; it uses the same backend as the "classic" Jupyter Notebooks but the UX and capabilities are very much different (in the same way as Visual Studio Code and
   Visual Studio are distinct). If it would be too many options, make it just "Jupyter Notebook/JupyterLab" (but then, by analogy to Visual Studio Code/Visual Studio, it would make sense to split it as well).

Comment: Ah, I saw this post too late :(

Answer (score 2):

I think that the section about other frameworks can include the Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF). A popular Java-based framework to deal with models and Model-Driven Engineering.

It's not in the hype as it was some years ago, but it could be interesting to see how people are dealing with it these days in the SO survey. Especially considering the code generation and code-assistance advance in the last few months. How does it compare with a more mature () solution that intends the same result?

It's mostly Java-driven, but it could be agnostic with some [Python implementations](https://pyecore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), for example, so it fits nicely in the "Other frameworks" session.

For relevance, the [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf?tab=Newest) is not so popular but active. I guess the EMF community is not so present at SO, but it'll be interesting to check if it's true.

References:
[Official website](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Modeling_Framework)

Answer (score 2):

I thought everything was already mentioned, except some unpopular tags, but then I saw Prolog and Fortran under **Programing languages**, and also lit and tidyverse (I don't know what this is) under **Other frameworks and libraries**.

Personally, I think that lists this year are too long for anyone to scroll (surely no one will read everything) and I don't think it's bad. Based on tag popularity, I think [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) and [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/) should be included under **Other frameworks and libraries**. Both are well known and more active tags than some tags I mentioned (I was surprised to find out that tidyverse is more active this year than OpenGL). Maybe also [Vulkan](https://www.vulkan.org/learn), [WebGL](https://get.webgl.org/) and [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) for comparison (but not very active).

I would like to see more technologies used for parallel programming, but I don't know many languages and frameworks. Maybe Chappel, [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) and [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), but I don't think they are popular.

My only concern with Prolog (and other technologies rarely used, and rarely seen in surveys) is that the list of languages is very long, so maybe the person who is still using it will not expect to see it in the survey.

Comment: Tidyverse is an opensource package set/framework used within the R-programming language: https://www.tidyverse.org

Answer (score 1):

[Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy) in the Cloud Platforms category.

Deno Deploy is a globally distributed serverless JavaScript hosting platform. Developers can deploy and run JS at the edge with zero config.

*Disclosure: I work at Deno!*

Answer (score 1):

JSF (Jakarta Server Faces or JavaServer Faces, as it was called before) is still a relevant web framework used mainly in larger companies.

Comment: [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Faces) it is now ***"Jakarta Faces"***, without "Server" (not necessarily correct; and it is currently internally inconsistent, unless they kept the abbr. "JSF" (not "JF")). Why do they keep changing the name? Is it tainted in some way?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Oracle "released" all the Java Enterprise technologies to be community-supported, but enforced its trademark on the name Java. The Eclipse Foundation was forced to rename everything (including the `javax` root package) and chose Jakarta, the largest city in Java, so at least all the acronyms could still use "J".

Answer (score -1):

I know it's too late for this year, but I wanted to comment on "Worked With and Want to Work With". Worked With is fairly clear, but Want to Work With... There are languages/frameworks/etc that I would like to try out for myself because I find something interesting about them, and there are those that I have to use at work. There's certainly some overlap there, but they also aren't identical, at all. I answered the survey by checking Want to Work With for anything that's in the union of those two sets, but it seems like that loses some information.

Answer (score -2):

I'd love to see [Qwik](https://qwik.builder.io/) included under Web frameworks and technologies

Answer (score -3):

Programming, scripting, and markup languages: Inform, Markdown, MicroPython, OpenSCAD

Cloud Platforms:  Arduino Cloud

Other frameworks and libraries:  MFC

Development Environments: Arduino, idle, PlatformIO

Operating Systems:  OpenVMS.  And where are the real-time OSes?

Developer Tools:  Seems very broad.  Should this include tools like ASAN, MSAN, TSAN, UBSAN, Valgrind, (Windows) Application Verifier, other static and dynamic analysis tools, etc.?  What about profilers? Vtune, ETW, perf, etc.

Communication Tools:  I'd bet #1 is email.  Too bad that's not on the list.

AI Development Tools:  I know a few developers who use ChatGPT to produce code to be used as a starting point.

Comment: [MFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) is ancient. Does it see significant use (not a rhetorical question; [Turbo C++](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-criticise-Yashavant-Kanetkar-books-like-Let-Us-C-Why-dont-more-people-use-Turbo-C) does)?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen:  Ancient?  No.  Antique?  Possibly.  Poking around on GitHub, I see MFC is the framework for thousands of public projects, including Bruce Dawson's actively maintained UIforETW (https://github.com/google/UIforETW).  Given inclusion of tech like Fortran, COBOL, and TempleOS, I don't see MFC as much of a stretch.

Comment: The Developer Tools section also seems to be missing bug tracking tools (Bugzilla, et al) and code review tools (Phabricator, Gerrit, etc.).

Answer (score -3):

I would say we are on the frontier of doing more web front-end development *without* heavy duty web frameworks such as the usual Angular, React or Vue. As such I would expect technologies such as [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) and [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) to start to make an appearance.

Answer (score -12):

Can [Hoylu Workspaces](https://www.hoylu.com/) be added to the collaboration tools?

It's a virtual canvas/whiteboard with templates for kanban, pull planning, retros, flow charts, notes, to name a few, and integrations with Jira, MS Teams, Webex, and a few more. Similar niche to Miro.

*Disclosure: Hoylu is the company I work for, Workspaces is a product I've never personally worked on, but use regularly.*

Comment: Why though? The company isn't even notable enough to have its own wikipedia page. Doesn't sound like it'd make for an interesting data point

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Why not? Is having a wiki page a necessity? They are easy to create from what I understand. I've not ever heard of many of the tools already listed and don't care enough to research if they have a wiki page to be considered "notable" enough. They were notable enough *someone* knew of and included them. Anyway, this is just a request. :)

Comment: Quite a few tools don't have wikipedia pages (because companies do, but tools generally don't), but they generally [have other stats to back up notability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424311/6296561). A wikipedia page is indeed not required, but when you're pushing a project you are affiliated with, that appears to have next to no users, and no public notability beyond having a single page ranked for "hoylu" (followed by the first page being dominated by an artist by the same name) in the three search engines I checked, it seems like spam at worst and an uninteresting data point at best

Comment: There's also plenty of stuff that's going to get excluded for not being notable. I have several things I've made for instance, but that won't be listed (and that I wouldn't try to list anyway, because it'd be a boring data point). Notability, while not explicitly defined as a measurable quantity in "must have a wikipedia page" or "at least x amount of users", does matter for inclusion in the survey